# Python's equivalent of Java's statement.getGeneratedKeys()?

Tags: java, python, database, jdbc, sqlite

Is there an API in Python's sqlite3 module similar to Java's statement.getGeneratedKeys()? If not, what is the best way to get recently autogenerated keys in Python with sqlite3?

Comment: Wow, I have been using JDBC for a long time and I didn't even know that `Statement` had that method! I suppose that's what you get when you work with Oracle primarily. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQLite function `last_insert_rowid()`. From the [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

> The last_insert_rowid() function
>   returns the ROWID of the last row
>   insert from the database connection
>   which invoked the function. The
>   last_insert_rowid() SQL function is a
>   wrapper around the
>   sqlite3_last_insert_rowid() C/C++
>   interface function

Comment: In Python you mean [Cursor.lastrowid](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.lastrowid)? I realized just now while going through the docs. To get the keys I'll have to make a SELECT query with this rowid. I was wondering if its possible to avoid that.

Comment: Yes, it's eqivalent to SQLite's last_insert_rowid().